Generic Async Task inside WPF Window - Autocad API
I have a generic WPF Window, it uses the MVVM pattern. So, once it's declared, it receives a ViewModel object. The objective of this Window is to be shown to the user while long operations run in an Autocad API enviroment. All my code is inside a dll file.
How can I pass a method from other class to be run inside the StartTask method?
Must be a generic way, because many methods could be called from inside this Window. Could be done inside the ViewModel object.
public partial class BusyIndicatorView : Window
{
    internal BusyIndicatorViewModel BusyIndicatorViewModel { get; set; }

    public BusyIndicatorView(BusyIndicatorViewModel busyIndicatorViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BusyIndicatorViewModel = busyIndicatorViewModel;
        StartTask();
    }

    private async void StartTask()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // I gotta run here the generic method
            }

            Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }
}

The async method StartTask, inside the Window, is the way I have found to make the interface responsive while runnning heavy work.
Declaring the Window and the task, as the following way, doesn't fit my needs, because the Window is not responsive. Autocad API does not support multithread.
var heavyTask = new HeavyTask();
var window = new Window();
heavyTask.Start();
window.Show();

I'm expecting to have a window, that is showed while a long operation is running. The window shows the progress and is responsive, allowing the user move it, and click buttons.

Autocad API does not support multithread Start from wrapping it into Task.Run

BTW MultiThread is when you perform actions from multiple threads on a single instance. What you want is async. But adding only the async keyword to a method does not make it async, you need more for that

@MustafaMutasim I think that's not correct. As long as you are not referencing AutoCad APIs you can of course create background threads. AutoCad uses thread affine resources. You would have to marshall any call the API to the main thread.

@BionicCode, I think that's not correct I agree with you, but while OP tried private async void StartTask() and it didnot work, that an indicator of something wrong, anyway the answer you provided is high-level, I hope it works for him. Thanks!

@MustafaMutasim He wrote "The async method StartTask, inside the Window, is the way I have found to make the interface responsive while runnning heavy work." - So to me it sounds like he found a way to keep the UI responsive. He is only looking for a dynmaic solution to avoid hard coding the async operation into the BusyIndicatorView: "How can I pass a method from other class to be run inside the StartTask method?". That's how I read it ;)

@BionicCode, I guess he is looking for IAsyncEnumerable .. yield return let's see his reply

@MustafaMutasim I don't see any enumeration. StartTask isn't even supposed to return anything. He just wants to dynamically tell the BusyIndicatorView to execute work.  In other words, the same BusyIndicatorView must be able to perform any kind of operation that is passed to the StartTask method.

@BionicCode, I don't see any enumeration Yes but there are lot of code he didn't show, I said that maybe he has a huge data he want to display some when arrived instead of waiting for a long time. StartTask isn't even supposed to return anything correct, maybe he stuck there looking for the 2nd step

@MustafaMutasim Yes, we don't know this, you are right. But he asked a very specific question which we can address.

Usually, you wouldn't have your busy indicator doing any work except for spinning or showing profress. Usually, you would start the background task and then show the busy indicator until that task has completed. You may update the busy indicator from the background task using Progress<T> in case it shows progress.

in case it shows progress await Task.WhenAll(Tasks_List) would be better in his case because he mentioned multithreading, as you know there is unlimited solutions depending on the situation and knowledge

The WPF window must be reusable. Sometimes it will show a spinning wheel, and other times a progress bar. Some text, etc. I don't want to hardcode the long operation methods inside it, because more methods are going to be added. The Tasks, are going to be drawing insertions, data access, and sometimes ploting (PDF). The WPF window is a great way to block the user interaction with the program (declared as modal window) while showing the progress.

You should never run any long-running and/or async code from a constructor. This is a code smell as type construction is supposed to return fast in the same manner a field or property does not silently run long-running operations.
The other problem is that constructors can't be async. To solve this problem, you must let the owner of the type explicitly start the async operation or long-running initialization e.g. by providing a Initialize or InitializeAsync method. This way the method can have a correct async Task signature (instead of async void).
In your case you could make StartTask public and let it accept a delegate as argument.
The following example adds a ShowAsync method to the API of BusyIndicatorView that enables the caller to pass in an async delegate:
Usage example
private async Task ShowBusyIndicator()
{
  var busyIndicatorViewModel = new BusyIndicatorViewModel();
  var busyIndicator = new BusyIndicatorView(busyIndicatorViewModel);
  
  // Start a non-cancellable opertaion
  await busyIndicator.ShowAsync(DoSomethingAsync);

  var cancellationTokeSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

  // Start a cancellable operation
  try
  {
    await busyIndicator.ShowAsync(DoSomethingCancellableAsync, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    // TODO::Perform clean up if necessary
  }
}

private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{}

private async Task DoSomethingCancellableAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{}

BusyIndicatorView.xaml.cs
public partial class BusyIndicatorView : Window
{
  private Func<CancellationToken, Task> cancellableAsyncOperation;

  internal BusyIndicatorViewModel BusyIndicatorViewModel { get; }

  public BusyIndicatorView(BusyIndicatorViewModel busyIndicatorViewModel)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    BusyIndicatorViewModel = busyIndicatorViewModel;
    //StartTask();
  }

  public async Task ShowAsync(Func<Task> asyncOperation)
    => ShowAsync((token) => asyncOperation.Invoke(), CancellationToken.None);

  public async Task ShowAsync(Func<CancellationToken, Task> cancellableAsyncOperation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    this.cancellableAsyncOperation = cancellableAsyncOperation;
    Show();
    await StartAsync(cancellationToken);
  }

  private async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    try
    {
      await this.cancellableAsyncOperation.Invoke(cancellationToken);
      Close();
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
      // TODO::Perform clean up if necessary

      throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) // <-- Code smell
    {
      //MessageBox.Show("Error"); 
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // At least show the message
    }
  }
}

